# FSCalendar jumps to year 1970

Tags: ios, swift, reload, reloaddata, fscalendar

I'm trying to reload FSCalendar using Dispatch main queue.
it works fine but it causes the calendar to jump all the way back to 1970 
how can i prevent this from happening? or set the date to current date again ? 
here is my code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    self.calendar.firstWeekday = 7
    self.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    self.calendar.select(Date())
    self.calendar.identifier = NSCalendar.Identifier.persian.rawValue
    self.calendar.reloadData()
}
```

btw this issue has nothing to do with Dispatch. reloading it in other forms causes the same problem too.

Comment: I've never used `FSCalendar`, but are you sure, `calendar.reloadData()` shouldn't happen after you change the data? To me it seems like the logical approach to first change the data, then reload the calendar.

Comment: @DávidPásztor tried that. Unfortunately, it doesn't  fix the problem,

Comment: A date in 1970 typically indicates that the actual date timestamp has been set to 0, or is missing. I haven't used FSCalendar but I'd check that it's getting a nonzero date value.

Comment: @TomHarrington that's not the case here. if that was the problem the calendar should still have problems when I remove reloadData(). but that doesn't happen

Comment: @Farbod unless it's happening as a side-effect of calling `reloadData`.

Comment: @TomHarrington i checked it  and timestamp isn't set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

For current date you have to first get current month position. For that you must add two method of `FSCalendarDelegate`

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition)   -> Bool {
    return monthPosition == .current
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {

    return monthPosition == .current
}
```

Hope this will help you.